# How can I reperesent yearwise data in ssrs 2005 when I have monthwise query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I Have a such dataset where the query parameter is month name.

[image]

Now I have to represent a report of the year this way, where qty will be the totalQty of the month and value will be the TotalValue.

[image]

How should I do this. Do I need to use matrix in the ssrs or write a new query. I am not familiar with using matrix.
My current Query is,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRPTMonthlyProductionSummaryFORATL]
    @MonthName  Varchar(50)
-- Exec spRPTMonthlyProductionSummaryFORATL 'Sep,2014'
AS BEGIN
Declare @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime
Select @FromDate = Convert(Datetime,@MonthName), @ToDate = DateAdd(d,-1,DateAdd(m,1,Convert(Datetime,@MonthName)))
Declare @SQL nVarchar (4000)
SET @SQL = '
WITH
    allocations AS (
        SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit2_Qty,
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit3_Qty,
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value, 
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit2_Value, 
        CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value
    FROM LineAllocation LA
    INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
    INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
    INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
    INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
    INNER JOIN OrderMasterCostBreakdown OCB ON OCB.OrderRefID= OM.OrderRefID
    INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcess PP ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId
    where UseDate = @MonthName AND ProcessName =''Sewing'' 
    )
SELECT 
    BUYER, 
Unit1_Qty,
Unit2_Qty,
Unit3_Qty,
Unit1_Value, 
Unit2_Value, 
Unit3_Value,
(ISNULL(Unit1_Qty,0) + ISNULL(Unit2_Qty,0) + ISNULL(Unit3_Qty,0)) as TotalQty,
(ISNULL(Unit1_Value,0) + ISNULL(Unit2_Value,0) + ISNULL(Unit3_Value,0)) as TotalValue
FROM allocations;'

EXEC sp_executesql
@sql
,N'@MonthName varchar(30)'
,@MonthName = @MonthName;
End
```

Comment: Can you give your Table structure ? And input data not what your current query is returning ?

Comment: I am not clear what should I provide @Coder of Code

Comment: The table structure from which you are fetching the data like colmn names and datatype ? and the some dummy data for that tables ? And your current query post it in the question

Comment: @Coder of Code I have added my current query in the qs.

Comment: Select the `UseDate ` as month and then apply the group by on the `UseDate/Month` column and that will give you the groupby data for each month and then just adjust that data on report.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: What is the value of the `UseDate` ? Is it Datetime ?

Comment: Yes. It is Datetime.

Comment: What is value of the `UseDate` ? can you post ? What is your parameter value for `@MonthName` ?

Comment: My parameter value is  like "Sep,2014" or "Aug,2014"

Comment: Do you want to show the report for one year at a time right ?

Comment: Right. i got month totals from the query. I want to show only the totals for each month of a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to show the report for one year starting from the `Jan` to `Dec`

```
WITH
allocations AS (
    SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit2_Qty,
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit3_Qty,
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value, 
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit2_Value, 
    CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value,
    UseDate
FROM LineAllocation LA
INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
INNER JOIN OrderMasterCostBreakdown OCB ON OCB.OrderRefID= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcess PP ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId
where YEAR(UseDate) = @YearToShow AND ProcessName =''Sewing'' 
)
SELECT 
  BUYER, 
  Month(UseDate) AS Month,
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit1_Qty,0)) Unit1Quantiry,
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit2_Qty,0)) Unit2Qunatity,
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit3_Qty,0)) Unit3Quantity,
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit1_Value,0)) Unit1Value, 
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit2_Value,0)) Unit2Value, 
  SUM(COALESCE(Unit3_Value,0)) Unit3Value,
  SUM(COALESCE((ISNULL(Unit1_Qty,0) + ISNULL(Unit2_Qty,0) + ISNULL(Unit3_Qty,0)),0)) as TotalQty,
  SUM(COALESCE((ISNULL(Unit1_Value,0) + ISNULL(Unit2_Value,0) + ISNULL(Unit3_Value,0)),0)) as TotalValue
FROM allocations
GROUP BY
    Month(UseDate),Buyer;
```

This will give you the monthwise some for the entire year. Which you will pass as the `@YearToShow` parameter.

**This query is not tested**.

Comment: facing problem in converting datetime to year as @yershow

Comment: Just use the `Year`  function with `@yershow ` if it is DateTime type.